# iOS Test Reports from Kiwi on TeamCity

Tags: ios, teamcity, kiwi

I'm looking into capturing test reports on TeamCity. The iOS testing framework being used is Kiwi, and I was wondering if the tool xcpretty would be able to capture Kiwi's output?

https://github.com/supermarin/xcpretty

Answer (score 0):

Xcpretty provides us option to output Test result file, which follow Junit format. Then you use XML report processing to parse the test result file.